# Csvhelper and excel manipulatiion

Tags: csvhelper

CSVHelper is great tool for CSV manipulation (read/write), but is there any way to use this tool to read/write excel files as well? I would like to combine it also to be able to read/write to excel e.g from csv or to csv.

Answer (score 3):

I was recently made aware of this CsvHelper extension: [CsvHelper.Excel](https://github.com/christophano/CsvHelper.Excel). I have not used it myself but it appears that it may fulfill your needs. Behind the scenes it uses the ClosedXml library.

Comment: Does anyone know does this excel library can be combine with csvhelper for excel part conversion and contain enough tools for excel manipulation like with/without mapp file?

Comment: There are several open source .NET libraries for reading Excel files, and also several proprietary tools as well. I don't know that you'll get much integration with CsvHelper though. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: **Warning** at this time (dec 2019) the CsvHelper.Excel library is no more compatible with the latest CsvHelper library API See https://github.com/christophano/CsvHelper.Excel/issues/10

Comment: @Steve ...Dammit!

Comment: @Steve it is now, [been moved to a new repo](https://github.com/youngcm2/CsvHelper.Excel).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently completed a small utility that uses the CSVHelper Excel Extension and so would like to present to you that it works.
Just use this particular library if you want to replicate the same results.
https://github.com/youngcm2/CsvHelper.Excel
[image: Chris Young's Nuget Package]
To use this library, once you define the Headers and the sources, you just need to understand the basic reading and writing steps.

Github Link to the code below: [Sapphire Code](https://github.com/parasparmar/PratikParmar)

**Class Definition**

The Sapphire Class contains all the headers present in the excel file. Spaces, Dashes, Underscores are all replaced. It **Optionally** implements the IEquatable interface with 2 methods Equals and GetHashCode so that comparisons between Source and Destination data are easier.

```
public class Sapphire : IEquatable<Sapphire>
{
    public int Sno { get; set; }
    public string Requestid { get; set; }
    //...... More Properties
    public bool Equals(Sapphire? other)
    {
        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return Requestid.Equals(other.Requestid);
    }
    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {

        //Get hash code for the Name field if it is not null.
        int requestid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Requestid) ? 0 : Requestid.GetHashCode();
        //Calculate the hash code for the product.
        return requestid;
    }

}

public class SapphireMap : ClassMap<Sapphire>
{
    public SapphireMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Sno).Name("SNo");
        Map(m => m.Requestid).Name("RequestID");
        //...... More Mapped Properties            
    }

}
```

**Reading**

The Sheet Name and HeaderPositions are passed in since we don't want CSVHelper to guess the same.

```
    using CsvHelper;
    using CsvHelper.Configuration;
    using CsvHelper.Excel;
public class SapphireHelper
    {    
public List<Sapphire> ReadToEnd(string file, string? SheetName = "Summary Report", int? HeaderLocatedAtRowNumber = 4)
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(new ExcelParser(file, "Summary Report", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
            {
                if (HeaderLocatedAtRowNumber > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < HeaderLocatedAtRowNumber; i++)
                    {
                        csv.Read();
                    }
                }
                csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<SapphireMap>();
                var configuration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                {
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    HeaderValidated = null,
                    MissingFieldFound = null,
                    IgnoreBlankLines = true,
                    ShouldSkipRecord = (records) => records.Record.All(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)
                };
                var records = csv.GetRecords<Sapphire>().ToList();
                return records;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Writing**

The Update method requests SapphireHelper to read data from both files and then compares both and using the distinct method updates the destination file. I've tried to keep this example simple and direct. But of course, tested the code's happy flow successfully.

```
public int Update(string source, string destination)
    {
        SapphireHelper sr = new SapphireHelper();
        var recordsAtDestination = sr.ReadToEnd(file: destination, SheetName: "Summary Report", HeaderLocatedAtRowNumber: 0);
        var recordsAtSource = sr.ReadToEnd(file: source, SheetName: "Summary Report", HeaderLocatedAtRowNumber: 4);
        recordsAtDestination.AddRange(recordsAtSource);
        WriteToDestination(destination, recordsAtDestination.Distinct());
        

        return 0;
    }

    private int WriteToDestination(string file, IEnumerable<Sapphire> payload)
    {           
        using (var writer = new ExcelWriter(file,"Summary Report"))
        {
            writer.WriteHeader<Sapphire>();
            writer.WriteRecords(payload);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

**Usage**

The usage is very simple and efficient. Just use the Sapphire Writer to update your destination with all files that are a part of your Source. The source files array is a simple string array of the file paths.
The oneLoneDestinationFile is also a single string path.

```
SapphireHelper writer = new SapphireHelper();
writer.Update(sourcefilesStringArray.ToString(), oneLoneDestinationFile.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You would have to combine it with a library that does excel separately.

Comment: Apologies, I used your library with Chris Young's Extension. And it works beautifully, my apologies for the above. I wish there were a way to take back that down vote.